# git authentication with Active Directory user

Tags: authentication, git, active-directory

I use `likewise-open` to connect to a Windows AD, and I am able to see AD users.

What should I do to authenticate a user for git when I push to and pull from a git repository? Where is this configured?

Answer (score 3):

There is already already [this script](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/contrib/ldap/ldap-query-example.pl) for *group* user authentication through AD, within **[gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)**, in the [`contrib/ldap` directory](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/tree/pu/contrib/ldap).
The idea remain to have an intermediate layer (here with gitolite, a ssh-based layer through [forced commands](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858)), which is able to authorized a git command based on the result of a LDAP query.

Comment: I must use ssh? I think about http.. So gitolite should solve authentication  problem? I configure it to use AD and to authenticate git repository directory ?

Comment: @netmajor: you need a layer which will have a way to identify the user, in order to match that user with an AD. If you layer has a way to get a user id, then it can be used to query the AD, as the script I mention illustrates. You don't have to use gitolite, but it is an example of such a layer having a secure way to check a user id (since the user has to have the proper private key in order to be matched to his/her deployed public key on the gitolite side).

Answer (score -1):

This my post on the subject (translated from Russian by Google).
Maybe it will help.

[GIT, AD and SSH. Or how to control access to the GIT through AD](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://habrahabr.ru/post/130187/)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.